# Problem with PHP Page connecting to DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$dbserver="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="root";

$link=mysql_connect("$dbserver","$username","$pass");
if(!$link){die('DB Connection Failed'.mysql_error()); }
echo('connected');
    $Name=$_POST["namei"];
    $ID=$_POST["pid"];
    $Address=$_POST["address"];
    $Phone=$_POST["phone"];

    $query="INSERT INTO contact(Name,ID,Address,Phone) VALUES('".$Name."',".$ID.",'".$Address."',".$Phone.");";

    echo($query);



?>
```

The code above is used by me to connect to a mysql db, i'm posting the contents to this page from an html page. As i checked there is no problem with POST. but on click of submit it gives me an error '500 Internal Server Error'.

I'm using Apache 2.2 Server, and mysql 5.5.

Can any one tell what is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: maybe look at apache error logs?

Comment: then paste html page code too

Comment: there must be  `header()` redirection problem

Comment: Execute `tail -f /var/log/apache/php.errors` and see what errors are listed. Also, please don't use `"$dbserver", "$username", "$pass"`. They are strings already so there is no reason to place them inside a string. Just use: `$dbserver, $username, $pass`.

Comment: I just used those variables on trying to clear the error. My apache dont say any error. It logs the access with Code 500.

Comment: HTML code i use is just a form with action="update.php"  on submit i'm just posting the form contents.

Comment: This may sound like a silly question, but did you set the password on your db? The reason I ask, is because, by default $pass=''. If so, ignore my stupid question. :) btw: I think @alex is referring to your lack of mysql_real_escape_string and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please run

```
<?php
echo 'phpversion: ', phpversion(), "<br />\n";
if ( !extension_loaded('mysql') ) {
    die('mysql module not available');
}
echo 'mysql_get_client_info: ', mysql_get_client_info(), "<br />\n";
die;
```

to check whether a) you can run *any* php script and b) the mysql_* functions are available.
Then try

```
<?php
echo "start<br />\n";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
flush();

$dbserver="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="root";

$link=mysql_connect($dbserver, $username, $pass);
if(!$link) {
    die('DB Connection Failed '.mysql_error());
}
echo "connected<br />\n";
if ( !mysql_select_db('dbname here', $link) ) {
    die('DB selection failed. '.mysql_error($link));
}
echo "db selected<br />\n";

$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['namei'], $link);
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pid'], $link);
$Address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'], $link);
$Phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'], $link);

$query = "
    INSERT INTO
        contact
        (Name,ID,Address,Phone)
    VALUES
        ('$Name', '$ID','$Address','$Phone')
";
echo '<pre>Debug: query=', htmlentities($query), "</pre>\n";
```

It prints something in any case (echo/flush) and sets [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) + [display_errors](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) so that error messages are sent to the client (you don't want that in production, don't forget to remove those lines).
I also added the necessary calls to [mysql_select_db()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_select_db) and [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (needed as soon as the script really sends the query to the mysql server).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the clue that, i commented the module of sql in php.ini earlier. But The problem is My apache wont start if i'm uncommenting it. Why it happens i dont know.

Comment: @Mr.K : And the underlying problem was ...?

Answer (score 0):

K,

You should add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To the beginning of your script.  This will stop the 500 errors and give you the proper error message so you have a better idea of what is going wrong.

It might be the `echo($query);` line, you only need `echo $query;` without the parentheses.